# Как настроить в Chrome панель разработчика так, чтобы при работе с ней, внешне был вид реального устройства?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить панель разработчика так, чтобы при работе вид был как на первом фото? Сейчас у меня внешка как на втором?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отображения рамки устройства, при активном режиме эмуляции вьюпорта надо вызвать меню (кнопка "три точки" вверху справа) и выбрать пункт "Show device frame":

[image: GIF]

Рамка отображается не у всех устройств которые можно добавить в список эмулируемых.
И, пункт меню для включения/отключения рамки устройства недоступен при выборе в списке устройств "Responsive", то есть режима свободного изменения размеров вьюпорта.

---

Больше "скинов" устройств (заявлено 54шт.) есть в браузере [Blisk](https://blisk.io), который тоже основан на исходном коде Chromium. То есть, это почти тот же Chrome - но без встроенной интеграции с гуглосервисами (такими как синхронизация), и с некоторыми дополнительными возможностями взамен (такими как отображение одновременно мобильного и десктопного вида страницы).
*// Должен оговориться, что у меня негативный опыт использования Blisk (глючил), но все же советую посмотреть-попробовать: возможно, его старые баги уже устранены...*

Comment: _«пункт меню для включения/отключения рамки устройства недоступен при выборе в списке устройств "Responsive", то есть режима свободного изменения размеров вьюпорта»_ - поэтому я не сразу заметил такую возможность, когда писал первую версию ответа: фишка в том, что упомянутый пункт меню **вообще не отображался** в режиме Responsive, пока я не включил рамку сменив режим на эмуляцию смартфона... Теперь пункт меню и в Responsive отображается (недоступным, конечно же). Уж не знаю, баг это, или меня переглючило :)